# How do I use geom_bar correctly with two rows of the same name?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tibble, geom-bar

[image: DataSet]

I have this data set and want to make a geom_bar similar to the one I provided.
[image: Geom_bar]

I want the geom_bar plot to have each one of the rows with the same name as different colors.
Similar to this:
[image: perfect expample.]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this. You have multiple values for the number of counts. So you can group by `NumAccounts` and create a reference variable so that each value can be plotted in a bar. For that you can use `mutate()` from `dplyr` and `group_by()` in order to have such id variable. Then the plot can be designed (Please next time include a sample of your data using `dput()`). Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Data
df <- data.frame(NumAccounts=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
                 MeanNumAccounts=c(73.36,64.74,431.5,340.98,226.14,693))
#Mutate group
df %>% group_by(NumAccounts) %>% mutate(ID=1:n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(NumAccounts),y=MeanNumAccounts,
              fill=factor(NumAccounts),group=factor(ID)))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',color='black',position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

Output:

[image]

And a more customized solution would be:

```
#Code 2
df %>% group_by(NumAccounts) %>% mutate(ID=1:n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(NumAccounts),y=MeanNumAccounts,
              fill=factor(NumAccounts),group=factor(ID)))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  labs(fill = 'NumAccounts',x='NumAccounts')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Well, each "1", "2", and "3" would need to be a different color :/. I'm modeling FB and Twitter accounts. I'm currently adding a new column to my df that details which NumAccounts belongs to which social media platform. Not much progress yet though.

Comment: @AntonioPano Do you mean having six different colors?

Comment: @AntonioPano You can adjust the fill option to be the social network. It is an option. Try with the code in the answer. It is the better way you can start your project.